# How to submit data via POST request from Angular to a .Net API

Tags: c#, angular

I am trying to call a simple request, but the value(property) in API is null. Do you have any suggestions?

C#

```
[Route("getpagefields")]
[AcceptVerbs(WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)]
public IHttpActionResult GetPageFields([FromBody]string property)
{
   USERS user = TokenUtils.Authonticate(Request);
                
   return Ok(new { fields = WebServiceBL.GetPageFields(property) });
}
```

.ts

```
GetPageFields(){
  debugger;
  let urlPart = this.router.url.split('/')[3];
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.set('data', urlPart);
  let test = this._httpClient.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+'users/getpagefields',params).subscribe(() => {   
 });
}
```

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: why do you send it as `HttpParams` ? it's supposed to be simple object...

Comment: @EliPorush because without I am getting error ' {message: "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.",…}
: 
"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'text/plain'."

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 3 Ways of submitting Data via POST-Request in Angular

You can either submit your data via request-body, via query-params or via request-header. I made one example for each of these possibilities:

---

**Submitting Data via Request-Body:**

If you want to submit data via body, you can wrap it in an object and pass it via the second parameter:

```
const myData = { id: '1', name: 'Lukas' };
this.http.post(url, myData).subscribe();
```

And your .Net backend-method will then expect and object that corresponds to `myData`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetPageFields([FromBody]MyDataObject myObject)
{
   var id = myObject.id;
   var name = myObject.name;
}
```

---

**Submitting Data via Query-Params:**

If you want to pass string values via `HttpParams`, they need to be passed as a property of third argument:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
                    .set('id', '1')
                    .set('name', 'Lukas');

this.http.post(url, null, { params });
```

And the corresponding .Net backend-method might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetPageFields([FromQuery] string id, [FromQuery] string name)
{
   var id = id;
   var name = name;
}
```

---

**Submitting Data via Request-Header**

In Angular you can submit data via Http-Header like this:

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
                    .set('id', '1')
                    .set('name', 'Lukas');    

const options = { headers: httpHeaders };

this.http.post(url, null, options);
```

And the corresponding .Net backend-method might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetPageFields()
{
    var id = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "id").Value.FirstOrDefault();
    var name = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "name").Value.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, without using this I am getting error :` {message: "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.",…}`

Comment: If you want to submit data via body, you might actually have to wrap it in an object. I adapted my example accordingly. And `GetPageFields()` will then expect an object and not a string.

Comment: I also added an example for the backend-method.

Comment: thanks, and if I wan to past it on header? (not so important by body)

Comment: I added all 2 more possibilities how to submit data: Via `Query-Params` and via `Request-Header`.

Comment: @Rachel: If it worked please tell me / mark my answer as the accepted answer.